# using reactor.kafka to either describe topic or get kafka metadata

Tags: apache-kafka, reactor-kafka

I am using `reactor.kafka.sender.KafkaSender`, `reactor.kafka.sender.SenderRecord` to connect to kafka and send messages.

here, the sender record initialises the connection lazily and takes more time for initial requests.

I want to add a call to either get kafka metadata or just describe a topic during init so that when actual requests come in, it'll be pretty fast.

I didn't find any solutions online, looked at reactor.kafka documentation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You use AdminClient to describe things in Kafka, not a Sender/producer. They use different protocols though, so it shouldn't speed anything up